# A simple circuit problem / maximum power

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image: I was solving a example from a book take a look]

Let us solve the first part for $R_{L}$. I used Thevenin to make its equivalent circuit. We get $R_{Th}$ or $R_{eq}=110/3=36.67$, so for maximum power transfer it must be equal to $R_{L}$. I can't point out my mistake.

Comment: Shortcut is to consider 20 ohms as an internal of cell. And r=20=req of the parallel side Branch.

Comment: sir using thevenin theorem we can make this circuit a simple cell connected to  a resistance  and our load resistance. now in this equivalent circuit simply both resistance should equal. that's what i did.but the book says different story

Comment: its not home work.if it was i could just copy it,you see solution is right there. it's a doubt just imagine you make it to question 39 without stopping and you are about to complete the chapter suddenly a very easy question pop ups and pull the brakes , and you cant point out what went wrong. AHH it make my brain explode. so can you just forget about formality and help me out

Comment: What you want in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way of solving this problem is to convert all of the circuit except for $R_{\rm L}$ into the Thevenin equivalent at that does produce a maximum power value when $R_{\rm L} = \frac {110}{3}\,\Omega$.

The longer method attempted by the textbook produces a current through $R_{\rm L}$ which is equal to $\dfrac{60}{110+3R_{\rm L}}$ which gives the power dissipated in that resistor $P= \dfrac{60^2R_{\rm L}}{(110+3R_{\rm L})^2}$.

Implicit differentiation with respect to $R_{\rm L}$ and making $\frac {dP}{dR_{\rm L}}=0$ gives $P(110+3R_{\rm L}) = 600$ and then substituting for $P$ does give the same value for $R_{\rm L}$ as via the Thevenin method.

Comment: so what did text book do wrong since answers are different

Comment: Yes, for some reason the current passing through the battery was used.

Comment: okay so one last time i am right and the book is wrong

Answer (score -1):

The given solution does not make sense. As you correctly indicated, *for maximum power delivered to $R_L$*, the load resistance must equal the Thevenin resistance of the circuit $R_L$ is connected to, not the equivalent resistance connected to the battery. This means
$$ R_L = R_{th} = \frac{110}{3}\ \Omega. $$